# Which Ember Data version to use with Ember.js 1.0.0-pre2?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm attempting to use Ember Data with Ember.js version 1.0.0-pre2. The Ember docs on the website say just to download Ember Data from GitHub. This isn't working because Ember Data is trying to call [`Ember.merge()`](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/commit/fb6482364432152d6093145eeee38e2ad68cb309#L0R202) which isn't present in the 1.0.0-pre2 release.

Which version combo of Ember and Ember Data am I supposed to be using? I tried using the latest commit from Ember's master branch but it breaks my App's router, so I assume it isn't stable.

Here's a copy of my router that breaks in the latest versions (I believe it was pasted from an Ember code sample):

```js
 
var App = Ember.Application.create({ });
App.Router = Ember.Router.extend({
    enableLogging: true,
    root: Ember.Route.extend({
        aRoute: Ember.Route.extend({
            route: '/',
            enter: function(router) {
              console.log("entering root.aRoute from", router.get('currentState.name'));
            },
            connectOutlets: function(router) {
              console.log("entered root.aRoute, fully transitioned to", router.get('currentState.path'));
            }
        })
    })
});
```

Comment: Get the latest from both Ember and Ember-Data repositories and build them. While Ember-Data is still under 1.0, you should always use the latest release available (currently revision 11), but you'll have to build them yourself.

Comment: I tried doing that but using the latest commits from both master branches appears to be unstable. Among other things, my App's router stops working (can't even get enableLogging to take effect).

Comment: Can you post a minimum code with your definition for the Router? I've built Ember today and I have the router working fine on my end.

Comment: I've updated my question with the exact code sample that wasn't working.

Comment: just a heads up.. 1.0pre2 isn't the *latest* latest, there are new bits available in the master branch. If you build from there, you'll notice that the Router has been drastically changed and this code won't work. I'd say you should use the new router going forward since it should be out pretty soon, replacing (and potentially breaking applications in the process) the current aka old Router

Comment: Are there any examples or docs on the new Router changes?

Comment: The http://emberjs.com/guides/ on the emberjs.com website has been updated to demonstrate the new router.

Comment: @c4p: To me the docs seems to be woefully inadequate without an updated starter kit to accompany them.  Also, the "ember-latest" is broken and requires fixes that don't have an official build yet.  Seems the whole new router stuff is a bit unstable right now, though I guess technically the whole thing is still a preview release :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use Ember Data with the version of Ember.js distributed on their website (1.0.0-pre2), the newest version you can use is revision 10. The commit this corresponds to isn't documented anywhere, I had to step through the commits and find it. I've compiled it and uploaded it here in case anyone else needs it:

[Latest Ember Data Revision 10 Build](https://gist.github.com/4457920)

Comment: There is a newer version. I've been using revision 11 for a while.

Answer (score 1):

You only need to build the latest Ember-Data... the result will be found in the 'dist' directory.  You can also find the version of Ember.js that that particular build of Ember-Data relies on within that directory as well.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

After cloning the repo I was able to get REVISION 10 by doing a reset --hard:

```
git clone https://github.com/emberjs/data.git ember-data.git                                                             
cd ember-data.git
git reset --hard 796cc1920f53dbe858430cb142f7432f32251f06
```

That got me running again.

Answer (score 0):

`Git clone https://github.com/emberjs/data.git` and set the right revision when you delare your store.

```
APP.store = DS.Store.create({
    revision: 11
})
```

You'll be instructed if you're using anything that has been deprecated. I think you'll be better off  with newest version as things are moving quickly and thus bugs getting fixed.